# Mobile Development Newbie Setup SDKs and Development Enviroment. NOKIA

Tags: windows-vista, qt-creator, nokia, s60, series-40

I am trying to install development enviroments of Nokia. Can someone help me setup please, and point to some good tutorials that can give me some confidence and development start. I have downloaded most of QT Creator from Nokia. But need help in it.

If someone can help me get complete development setup for Windows Vista. I am installing QT Creator of Nokia, SDKs of Nokia. What else do I need for Nokia application development. That includes Java applications for S40 and S60.

All I am asking here is setup details of tools required to major mobile devices correct setup on Vista. Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Qt tutorial](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/tutorials.html) by Nokia
- J2ME development [tutorials](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/wtoolkit/)
- Qt development for S60 [tutorials](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2009/12/03/tutorial-videos-qt-development-for-symbian/)

Comment: Thanks dude! Appreciate it! But I already know these tutorials ;)